# Visual Studio Code: clang: error: no input files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, error-handling, clang

I ran a line of code in C++ on Visual Studio Code, however this message appeared on my screen.

clang: error: no input files

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Odds are you've misconfigured VSC. Pretty easy to do. Hopefully some one will be a long shortly with a list of json files you need to add to the question so that they can tell you what you got wrong.